# Cyclic dependency error when Binding to properties of child component in ngFor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm trying to bind to input properties on a child component inside of a ngFor loop to create a menu structure. 
*I haven't been able to find anything in my searches to help, so I'm posting this question.*

I'm storing the menu structure in code in the **sidebar** component as an array of ***MenuItemComponents*** -> **MenuStructure**

**sidebar.component.ts:** (Parent component)

```
export class SidebarComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  MenuStructure: MenuItemComponent[] = [];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //Define and Add Dashboard
      var dashboard = new MenuItemComponent(null);
      dashboard.title = 'Dashboard';
      dashboard.iconName = 'dashboard';

    //Define Documentation
      var documentation = new MenuItemComponent(null);
      documentation.title = 'Documentation';
      documentation.iconName = 'insert drive file';

    this.MenuStructure.push(dashboard);
    this.MenuStructure.push(documentation);
  }
}
```

This is the child component (aka. the building block of the menu):

**menu-item.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-item',
  templateUrl: './menu-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-item.component.css']
})
export class MenuItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() iconName: string;
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() children: MenuItemComponent[] = [];
  @Input() routeLink: string = '';

  constructor(private parent: MenuItemComponent) { }
```

**menu-item.component.html:**

```
<a><i class="material-icons">{{iconName}}</i><span>{{title}}</span>
    <i class="material-icons" >&#xE313;</i> 
</a>
```

The above template is used in a ngFor loop in the sidebar template...

**sidebar.component.html:**

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of MenuStructure">
        <app-menu-item [title]='item.title' [iconName]='item.iconName'>
        </app-menu-item>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

However when trying to implement this, I get the following template error:

```
Template parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! MenuItemComponent ("<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of MenuStructure">
            [ERROR ->]<app-menu-item [title]='item.title' [iconName]='item.iconName'>
            </app-menu-item>
      "): SidebarComponent@9:12
```

Can anyone shed some light on why it is complaining / a fix, and/or a better way to do this in angular 2?

Comment: sorry I checked. you are right.So i deleted my answer. I think in your case it is a dependency-injection error. constructor(private parent: MenuItemComponent) i think you are getting error because of this.Are you sure you can use routeLink directly because it is used by router & and its a kind of special variable ?

Comment: routeLink is not in use in my simplified example, but you were right about the MenuItemComponent being injected into the constructor, I don't think the dependency injector was smart enough to create a seperate reference and/or I've got the design wrong, so I'll have to try and figure out how to add a reference to the parent without passing it into the constructor (prob will just use property injection).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Amit, the error I was getting was generated from passing `private parent: MenuItemComponent` into the MenuItemComponent constructor (it's own constructor).

I falsely assumed that the dependency injector would create a different reference/instance for it and stop there, but turns out it was creating an infinite loop.

At this stage, I still haven't found a better solution on how to implement a Menu with children in angular 2 using components / sub-components, so anyone with a better solution is welcome to add an answer, but this answer addresses the error directly.